# HTML table not updating when data changed

Tags: d3.js, html-table

I'm building a chart with an accompanying table. The data for both comes from html input elements with data provided by the user. For now I'm just working on getting the table to update when the user clicks the submit button.

The first time the user clicks the submit button, the table displays correctly, however, on subsequent clicks the table is not updated, even though the underlying data is correctly updated (the global variable `cashflows` contains the user-entered data).

The code is shown below, but I also have a jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/cyclical/xcGSu/5/
(selecting the Load Sample Data button will populate some sample data).

If the table updates correctly on the first click, doesn't that indicate that the data is bound correctly to the DOM?

Thanks,
Neil

```
var dollars = d3.format(",.2f");

function sampleData() {
    d3.select("#cf1")[0][0].value=50000;
    d3.select("#dt1")[0][0].value = "2007-05-10";
    d3.select("#cf2")[0][0].value = 20000;
    d3.select("#dt2")[0][0].value = "2011-01-11";
    d3.select("#cf3")[0][0].value = 50000;
    d3.select("#dt3")[0][0].value = "2012-07-19";
    d3.select("#cf4")[0][0].value = 40000;
    d3.select("#dt4")[0][0].value = "2012-08-03";
    d3.select("#endMV")[0][0].value = 190551.29 ;
    d3.select("#endDate")[0][0].value = "2013-09-30";  
}

d3.select("#sample") 
     .on("click", sampleData); 


var cashflows = [];
var total = 0;
var irr = 0;

// bind the cashflows array to a table for display 
var column_titles = ['Date','Cashflow','Days','IRR Cashflow'];
var columns = ['date','cf','days','irr_cashflow'];

d3.select("#results").selectAll('table').data([0]).enter().append('table');
var table = d3.select('table');

table.selectAll('thead').data([0]).enter().append('thead');
var thead = table.select('thead');

table.selectAll('tbody').data([0]).enter().append('tbody');
var tbody = table.select('tbody');

table.selectAll('tfoot').data([0]).enter().append('tfoot');
var tfoot = table.select('tbody');


// append the header row
thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(column_titles)
    .enter()
    .append("th")
    .attr("align", function(d) {if (d=='Date') { return "left"} else { return "right"}})
        .text(function(column) { return column; });



function calculateIRR(){ 

        cashflows = [];

    var cfvalues = [];
    var cfdates = [];

    // get cashflows
    d3.selectAll("input.cashflow")[0]
        .forEach(function(d,i) { 
            if (d.value) {cfvalues.push( 1 * d.value )}; 
            }
         )


    // get dates
    d3.selectAll("input.cfdate")[0]
        .forEach(function(d,i) { 
            if (d.value) {cfdates.push( d.value)}; 
            }
         )

    // get ending MV and associated date; MV is multiplied by -1
    cfvalues.push(-1 * d3.select("#endMV")[0][0].value);
    cfdates.push(d3.select("#endDate")[0][0].value);

    // convert date strings to date objects
    var dates = cfdates.map(function(d) { return new Date(d.replace(/-/g, "/"))});

    // calculate the IRR; use 5% as starting value 
    var rate = XIRR(cfvalues ,dates, .05);  
    irr = rate;


var r = d3.select("#ratedisplay").selectAll("div")
   .data([rate])
     .enter()
     .append("div")
     .attr("class","rate")
        .text(function(d,i) {return "IRR: " + d}); //{return "IRR:" + dollars(d) + ""});


    var len = cfvalues.length;
    var last_day = dates[len -1];

    // construct final cashflow array for binding
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {  
        var cf_days = moment(last_day).diff(moment(dates[i]), 'days');

        var irr_cashflow = FV(rate, cf_days/365 , 0, cfvalues[i],0);
        total += irr_cashflow;

                cashflows.push(
                {'cf': cfvalues[i], 'date': dates[i], 'days' : cf_days, 'irr_cashflow': irr_cashflow}       
            );
    };


var rows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(function(d) {return cashflows} )
    .enter()
    .append("tr");



var cells = rows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(row) {
        return columns.map(function(column) {
            return {'name': column, 'value': row[column]};
        });
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .attr("align",function(d) {
        if (d.name == 'date') { return "left" } else {return "right"}
    })
        .html(function(d) { 
           if (d.name == 'date') {
                return d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d")(d.value);
           } else {
                return dollars(d.value);
           }     
        });


rows.exit().remove(); 
cells.exit().remove();

}

d3.select("#submit") 
     .on("click", calculateIRR);
```

Comment: In subsequent clicks, you have to handle the update and exit selections as well as the enter selection to change the displayed values. See e.g. [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html).

Comment: Thanks Lars... I originally had defined rows and cell variables and had `rows.exit().remove(); cells.exit().remove();` in the function (see updated above); but I would get the error `TypeError: rows.exit is not a function`.

Comment: More important in your case is the update selection.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I'm making some good progress; I've added the update and exit selections. The only issue I am experiencing now is that only the first row of the table is actually being updated... the others are not. I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyclical/xcGSu/11/

Comment: Actually, found the final issue, all solved now (jsfiddle updated). Thanks for your help Lars.